# It says 'str' object is not callable (python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error

I run the program and it says the problem is here:

```
print '_' * 10
```

It says `'str' object is not callable`, and I am really confused because there is no str in the whole code:

```
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" (abbrev, city)
```

Comment: Where does the `print '_' * 10` line fit in? The error message will not be about that line, and your code as posted doesn't include it.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call the string here:

```
"%s has the city %s" (abbrev, city)
#                    ^            ^
```

because Python sees that as `"..."(arg1, arg2)`, where the string is the object you are trying to call like you would a function or a class.

You forgot the `%` operator between the parentheses and the string:

```
print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)
#                          ^
```